# Clear session cookies with Selenium IDE?

Tags: cookies, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm writing [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) tests for an ASP application, and would like to test the cases when a session isn't properly initialized. Right now I'm clearing the cookies manually, but that is becoming a bit cumbersome.

*(ok, to be honest I forget it every fifth-or-so time and have to re-run the tests...)*

Is there a way in Selenium IDE to clear session cookies or fake a browser re-start?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found it myself, when I stopped thinking in terms of *clear* and tried *delete*:

- [deleteAllVisibleCookies](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/9f7086bcdb9775e4/ce37740453ea3188?lnk=gst&q=deleteallvisiblecookies#ce37740453ea3188)

Comment: deleteAllVisibleCookies doesn't clear the session cookies effectively. It olny clears the cookies of the currently visible domain.

Comment: Is there another way to delete all cookies for visible and non-visible domains?

Comment: Use `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();` to delete all cookies both visible and non-visible.

Comment: You can do this in IDE? I dont think so.

Comment: Nope, does not work for IDE. (Selenium IDE 3.17.2 and Firefox 97.0)

Answer (score 14):

I've found it most useful to simply begin all tests with a call to my logout page, and on that page purposely expire any sessions the user may have.

Comment: It seems like selenium won't delete HttpOnly cookies in firefox...?  http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=615

Comment: I don't get Selenium to delete the cookie I get my logout page to delete them.

Comment: I've found myself in the same place at the end :) +1

Answer (score 2):

```
deleteAllVisibleCookies
```

and put the site url in target

Answer (score 2):

use `deletecookies` or `deleteAllVisibleCookies` below is the example and you can get solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098556/not-able-to-delete-cookies-using-selenium-ide)

```
<tr>
<td>open</td>
<td>www.google.co.in</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td>deleteAllVisibleCookies</td>
 <td>PREF</td>
 <td>domain=.google.co.in, recurse=true</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>deleteAllVisibleCookies</td>
<td>NID</td>
  <td>domain=.google.co.in, recurse=true</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a PHP Project.

`deleteAllVisibleCookies()` removed too much for me. E.g. if a cookie for a rememberMe function was created by the application.

Instead I used `$this->deleteCookie('PHPSESSID');` which delete the session.