# Not able to delete cookies using selenium ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am not able to delete `cookies` using `selenium ide` .
I want to delete all my `cookies` before the `test case execution` 
i have tried

```
<tr>
    <td>deleteCookie</td>
    <td>ASP.NET_SessionId</td>
    <td>path=, domain=192.168.14.22:92, recurse=true</td>
</tr>
```

but its not working.

I also tried this

`deleteallvisible cookies` no luck.

Please suggest some idea to get override of this.

Comment: Here is the sort of kind of similar Question. [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664488/selenium-ide-deleteallvisiblecookies-and-asp-net-sessionid-cookie-not-working/7892607#7892607

Answer (score 4):

It isn't possible to delete the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie because it is marked [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTPOnly).

```
Set-Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=zecwj145rv2wkt45ekwangyq; path=/; HttpOnly
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085756/how-to-delete-session-cookie/1085792#1085792) there isn't anyway to delete or modify the cookie other than HTTP. There also [isn't a way to turn off HttpOnly for this cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247143/how-is-httponly-get-set-for-asp-net-sessionid-cookie/2247221#2247221).

Answer (score 3):

use this code to delete cookies through selenium ide, it work for and here is [image]
    Set base url is https://www.google.co.in

```
 <tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>deleteAllVisibleCookies</td>
     <td>PREF</td>
     <td>domain=.google.co.in, recurse=true</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>deleteAllVisibleCookies</td>
    <td>NID</td>
    <td>domain=.google.co.in, recurse=true</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Ya its working with google but its not working with the HttpOnly cookies, this commands fails to delete the cookies which are HttpOnly.

Comment: Can you give cookie name and Domain name or give me code I will check and let you know.

Comment: it's not working for local domain: local.snpts.org. I tried both `local.snpts.org` and `.local.snpts.org` as domain but still doesn't work.